# Why is Blender separating every face of this model when I unwrap it?

Tags: mesh, uv, faces, uv-image-editor

I have a problem with unwrapping this chair model.

I didn't mark any seams, then when I unwrapped the model, blender separated every face of the model as single island on the UV map. The same happened when I marked a seem all - mesh faces are split on the UV map

Any ideas how to unwrap it properly along the seams?

[image]

Comment: hello, could you please share your file? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: sure ;) https://we.tl/t-K6sRCEgKZ3

Comment: If you unwrapped already, there may be an existing UV map that blender thinks is "good enough", Go to the object data tab in the properties panel, and under UV Maps, hit the minus button next to the one that's there (remove it). Then unwrap again,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The faces of your object are all ripped apart, you need to select all, merge by distance, then mark seam and unwrap again.

Comment: Thank you. It's working :)